# Generator to merge sorted dictionary-like iterables

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, iterator, python-2.6

This is a variation on [Generator to yield gap tuples from zipped iterables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707273/generator-to-yield-gap-tuples-from-zipped-iterables) .

I wish to design a generator function that:

- Accepts an arbitrary number of iterables
- Each input iterable yields zero or more (k, v), k not necessarily unique
- Input keys are assumed to be sorted in ascending order
- Output should yield `(k, (v1, v2, ...))`
- Output keys *are* unique, and appear in the same order as the input
- The number of output tuples is equal to the number of unique keys in the input
- The output values correspond to all input tuples matching the output key
- Since the inputs and outputs are potentially large, they should be treated as iterables and not loaded as an in-memory dict or list.

As an example,

```
i1 = ((2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c'))
i2 = ((1, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'f'))
i3 = ((1, 'g'), (3, 'h'), (5, 'i'), (5, 'j'))
result = sorted_merge(i1, i2, i3)
print [result]
```

This would output:

```
[(1, ('d', 'g')), (2, ('a', 'e')), (3, ('b', 'f', 'h')), (5, ('c', 'i', 'j'))]
```

If I'm not mistaken, there's nothing built into the Python standard library to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there isn't a single standard library function to do what you want, there are [enough](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) [building](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) [blocks](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get you most of the way:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def sorted_merge(*iterables):
    for key, group in groupby(merge(*iterables), itemgetter(0)):
        yield key, [pair[1] for pair in group]
```

Example:

```
>>> i1 = ((2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c'))
>>> i2 = ((1, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'f'))
>>> i3 = ((1, 'g'), (3, 'h'), (5, 'i'), (5, 'j'))
>>> result = sorted_merge(i1, i2, i3)
>>> list(result)
[(1, ['d', 'g']), (2, ['a', 'e']), (3, ['b', 'f', 'h']), (5, ['c', 'i', 'j'])]
```

Note that in the version of `sorted_merge` above, we're yielding `int`, `list` pairs for the sake of producing readable output. There's nothing to stop you changing the relevant line to

```
        yield key, (pair[1] for pair in group)
```

if you want to yield `int`, `<generator>` pairs instead.

Comment: I think the only modification I'd do to this (in addition to your suggested generator change) is to replace itemgetter with a simple lambda.

Comment: @Reinderien your choice of course, but why? This is exactly what `itemgetter` is for ... and it's shorter, IMO more readable, and probably faster.

Comment: One less import, one less function for which docs must be read, and the alternative is simple enough. Only marginally, though.

Comment: Fair enough ... I'll stick with my preference, but it might interest you to know that [others agree with you](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18853227#18853227).

Comment: That being said, https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed prefers `operator` for speed, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Something a little different:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sorted_merged(*items):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for t in items:
        for k, v in t:
           result[k].append(v)
    return sorted(list(result.items()))

i1 = ((2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (5, 'c'))
i2 = ((1, 'd'), (2, 'e'), (3, 'f'))
i3 = ((1, 'g'), (3, 'h'), (5, 'i'), (5, 'j'))

result = sorted_merged(i1, i2, i3)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the default dict will eat my memory.